# How to replace a string using a wrapper function in Julia

Tags: arrays, regex, string, replace, julia

I am trying to write a Julia function that performs a find and replace operation on each element in an array of strings using regular expressions. It is essentially a wrapper around a broadcasted `replace()` call. If you are familiar with R's stringr package, this function should more or less work the same as `stringr::str_replace_all()`.

The code below replaces all instances of 'ee' with 'EE', replacing "greetings" with "grEEtings":

```
arr = ["hi", "hello", "welcome", "greetings"]
replace.(arr, r"e{2}" => "EE")
```

The function I wrote does not return modifications of the values in `arr`:

```
function str_replace_all(string::String, pattern::String, replacement::String)
    replace.(string, Regex(pattern) => replacement)
end

str_replace_all(arr, "e{2}", "EE")
```

What went wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you provided does not yet run, since you are trying to pass a String, but your function expects an Array of Strings. You either have to:

1. Remove the type annotation of `string::String` in the function definition, or
2. [vectorize](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-vectorized) your function when calling it, using the '.' syntax: `str_replace_all.(arr, "e{2}", "EE")`

It should also be noted that your function will not replace strings *in* the array, it will create a new array containing the replaced values. If you want to get the replaced values in your array, you could do something like (*Edit: as DNF noted in the comments, this way a new array is created and binded to the variable `arr`, which is not
really efficient*):

```
function str_replace_all(string, pattern::String, replacement::String)
    replace.(string, Regex(pattern) => replacement)
end

arr = str_replace_all(arr, "e{2}", "EE")
```

Comment: Moving the broadcasting to outside the function's body is a great idea, and probably makes the code's intent clearer to the user. In my code, I removed the broadcasting of `replace()` and instead use it when calling `str_replace_all()`.

Comment: This answer contains an error. The proposed code does _not_ modify the array `arr`. Instead, it creates a _new_ array, and then then re-binds the variable `arr` to point to that new array.

Comment: Thank you, @DNF, I left and edit to clarify that.

Answer (score 3):

drop type annotations in your function and it should work:

```
julia> arr = ["hi", "hello", "welcome", "greetings"]

julia> function str_replace_all(string, pattern, replacement)
    replace.(string, Regex(pattern) => replacement)
end
```

Comment: I don't think you should wrap the pattern in a `Regex`call. If it needs to be a regex, the caller should specify that. And if the original input is a String, then turning it into a Regex does not accomplish anything.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I wrote two methods in my code, one where pattern is a string and another where pattern is a regex. Great point!

Answer (score 3):

You have to actually modify the array:

```
function str_replace_all!(arr, pattern, replacement)
    arr .= replace.(arr, pattern => replacement)
end
```

You should put a `!` at the end of the function name to signal that it mutates the input. That is only a convention, it has no effect, but you should follow it nonetheless.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Doesn't `replace()` create a copy of the input? If so, wouldn't that mean it's better practice to leave out `!` in the function's definition?

Comment: `replace` creates a new string, yes, because strings are immutable. But `arr` is mutated. This is like an array of integers. You cannot mutate the integers, but you can mutate the array. In this case you mutate `arr`, so there should be a `!`

Answer (score 0):

After incorporating feedback from everyone's answers, here is my solution:

```
function str_replace_all(string::String, pattern::String, replacement::String)
    replace(string, pattern => replacement)
end
function str_replace_all(string::String, pattern::Regex, replacement::String)
    replace(string, pattern => replacement)
end
```

It is best to take advantage of multiple dispatch to allow users to decide on the type of pattern to send to `replace()`--an exact match (string) or a regular expression. Further, vectorization of the solution should be done when calling the function (e.g. `str_replace_all.()`) instead of being placed inside the function's body (as was the case with the call to `replace.()` in the OP).

Ex:

```
arr = ["hi", "hello", "welcome", "greetings"]
str_replace_all.(arr, "ee", "EE")
str_replace_all.(arr, r"e{2}", "EE")
```

Comment: Firstly, if you want `arr` to be modified in-place you must also assign to it, `arr .= ...`. Secondly, your function `str_replace_all` is now identical to `replace`, so you actually don't need it at all. Just use `replace` directly 

Comment: The main purpose of this post is to make a somewhat faithful recreation of `str_replace_all()` from R's stringr package. Therefore, this function is supposed to modify a copy of the string, not change where the array points. `arr .= ...` makes for a nice additional method to implement, however. Thanks for sharing. Recreating the stringr package in Julia was easier than committing the equivalent Julia functions to memory. stringr's naming convention is superb: every method begins with `str_`. An alias like this one allows people like me to do useful things with the language quickly.

Comment: Then the question is phrased in a somewhat confusing way, as it says: "The function I wrote does not replace any values in array arr. [...] What went wrong?" I'd also like to add that including the name of the type in a function name is not considered good style in Julia, and goes against the fundamental principles of multiple dispatch. You are of course free to do this, but it is not idiomatic.

Comment: All good points. Will clarify the function's goal in the question. As a convention, when does it become good practice to specify types in Julia functions? I'd imagine you'd want explicit types for performance-critical code or when writing extensions of methods, but are there other important reasons than these two?

Comment: It's not completely straightforward. Type declarations in function signature has no impact on performance, perhaps surprisingly. Rules of thumb are, no types in function signatures, except when you need different implementations for different types. You can of course still use signatures, eg. for documentation, or to signal that it only makes sense for some types, like Real. But careful, types _are_ needed in struct definitions, for performance.